# Javascript library to create calendar HTML

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

I'd like to find a Javascript library that will generate calenders (month views) dynamically. Something like

```
createCalendar(1, 2011)
```

to create a calendar for Jan 2011.

I also need to highlight certain days, so I would need to be able to either specify that in the createCalendar method or be able to select certain days using CSS selectors.

I do not need a datepicker. This is for display purposes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see this one?

[Jquery plugin calendar](http://www.webappers.com/2009/01/20/jquery-full-month-calendar-plugin-supports-events/)

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a smart option:

http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/

Comment: For the purpose of the above question, this lib looks nice. I am interested to use it when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at this one:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: FullCalendar is like the pioneer of calendar library that inspired another library named React Big Calendar : https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar that also looks nice to me. Currently I am trying several libraries, including these two and TUI Calendar : https://ui.toast.com/tui-calendar/ to include in my React app. All of these three libs are actively maintained. They also provide good documentations. Only after going into details, I will be able to decide which one I will use in my React app.